# Merge XML files with configurable rules (context: Maven POMs, Java)

Tags: java, xml, merge, maven, pom.xml

I'm currently writing some kind of a Maven POM preprocessor that assembles a POM for a project from multiple input files (basically a template and a module specific file). The files are hierarchically ordered (template = most general, module specific = least general). The problem is now to merge these files into a single POM file.

Long story short or if you're not familiar with Maven: a POM looks like this (shortened):

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Basically the merger shall **replace** all values of the more general file with the values of the more specific file (i.e. singletons, e.g. the `<modelVersion>` above) but there are certain elements where the merger shall **add** the more certain element to a parent (i.e. collections, e.g. `<dependency>` elements shall always be added to the `<dependencies>` element and no `<dependency>` element shall be replaced by another).

A more detailed example with definition of desired output:

File A:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>A</modelVersion>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupIdA</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactIdA</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

File B:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>B</modelVersion>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupIdB</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactIdB</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Desired output:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>B</modelVersion>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupIdA</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactIdA</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupIdB</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactIdB</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The set of collection type elements are known and should be configurable (preferably via a set of XPath expressions).

A Java based solution is appreciated.

What looked most promising so far was the tool mentioned [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2007/jw-07-xmlmerge.html) but the `MERGE` action produces something like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>groupIdAgroupIdB</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactIdAartifactIdB</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

when merging, which is not what I need.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

But isn't that all the purpose of the parent POM? Providing default value for most of used elements?

Comment: I'm not running a normal Maven build. Instead, I'm running a preprocessor that just builds the POM (i.e., it also builds the parent POM, so there's nothing there to inherit from).

The purpose behind this is that the preprocessor is part of a plugin that assembles projects dynamically from various modules that are spread across a subversion repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think that goal help:effective-pom [1] works exacly like you want.
Even if not, You can look into sources how they did this.

[1] http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html

Comment: If I would be running a normal Maven build, you would be right. Please see the comment I gave to Riduidel's answer about the purpose of this question. I will look into the sources of the help plugin anyway. Thanks for that hint.

Comment: I just looked up the code of help:effective-pom. They have the possibility to speak to the org.apache.maven.model.Model class as the help goal can only be executed on existing projects. That's not true for my purpose as I just have a bunch of java.io.File objects that shall be merged. That's also why my question was more targeted towards a general XML merge approach with customizable behavior for certain nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Java solution, but if you're interested in a Windows tool, [Project: Merge](http://www.projectmerge.com) will do that just fine.  You'll have to tell it which values it should choose (because it wont second guess for two-way merges), but it will do it.

You can set up the format specification for element identification so that it knows to use the character data inside <groupId> to identify <dependency> elements.  Once that's done it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, James. The tool looks good, but unfortunately a Windows only tool is no use for my purpose. I hacked together something myself in Java since posting the question, but I doubt it's 100% reliable. ;-)

Comment: Ah that's fair enough.  I wasn't convinced a Windows tools would be any use to you, but I figured I'd mention it on the off chance.  Do you think a Java version of the tool would be worth me looking into?